# Flex search box. Making button larger by adding space to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I'm trying to achieve a search form with the button appearing inside the text.

I the following codepen as a boilerplate, however, I'd like it so that if I add more text to the button (making it wider), it expands to left (inward on the container), rather than expanding the container.

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bYyvvz

CSS that works for the container:

```
.searchContainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.searchBox {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.searchButton {
  background: #538AC5;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Currently your `.searchContainer` does not have a width specified, so any content added to the search button will always expand the container.

You could solve this by specifying a `width` on the container and a `min-width` on the `searchBox` (to allow it to shrink).

```
.searchContainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 1 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}

.searchBox {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 30px;
}
```